# Setting up gateway on different subnet than IP address

Tags: networking, routing, windows-server-2012, gateway

My provider has a (stupid) setup where the IP address for the gateway is on a totally different IP range than the assigned IP address. They insist on doing this for whatever reason. I'm trying to get Windows Server 2012 R2 configured using a static route but have had no luck. I was able to get the network configured on FreeBSD using the following configuration in /etc/rc.conf:

```
ifconfig_vtnet0="inet 142.4.196.xxx netmask 0xffffffff"
static_routes="net1 net2"
route_net1="-net 192.99.16.254/32 -iface vtnet0"
route_net2="default 192.99.16.254"
```

Is there anyway to convert this so it will work on Windows Server 2012 R2? I've tried doing `route ADD 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0 192.99.16.254` but no luck.

Here's my IP address info:

```
IP Address: 142.4.196.xxx
(Required) subnet mask: 255.255.255.255
Gateway: 192.99.16.254
```

Comment: `My provider has a (stupid) setup where the IP address is totally different than the assigned IP address.` - That statement makes no sense. Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry, I meant ``My provider has a (stupid) setup where the IP address for the gateway is on a totally different IP range than the assigned IP address.``

Comment: Your netmask should be `0.0.0.0` and not `255.255.255.255` for you to be able to reach the route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OVH hosting does this same thing. the ip block you are assigned does not contain your gateway.

they provide per OS directions which perhaps can help you: http://help.ovh.co.uk/BridgeClient

your default route in your post will work, but you must provide a route to that gateway

Comment: My provider uses OVH and they referred me to a similar article (http://help.ovh.com/IpAlias) but there is no IP failover address provided.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to setup a static route, setting right netmask should be enough. You seem to have it set to `255.255.255.255`, but you need to set it to `0.0.0.0`

Comment: According to my provider, the netmask **MUST** be set to 255.255.255.255 otherwise OVH will block the IP address. Also, Windows Server 2012 R2 won't let me specify the net mask as 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

After finally getting a hold of my provider, it turned out the problem was that the MAC address was wrong and thus causing it to not connect. I didn't have to add any static routes or anything to get to work (luckily).